# why is my test receiving status 200 even though token is not provided?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, testing, jestjs

I defined `let token` and logged in before each implements, but in this one i simply `token = ''` to make sure that client is not logged in. I am supposed to get status 401 but instead i am getting 200. Can you tell me what i am doing wrong?

```
describe('PUT /:id', () => {

        let token;
        let genre;
        let newName;
        let id;

        const exec = async () => {
            return await request(server)
                .put('/api/genres/' + id)
                .set('x-auth-token', token)
                .send({ name: newName });
        }

        beforeEach(async () => {
            genre = new Genre({ name: 'genre1' });
            await genre.save();

            token = new User().generateAuthToken();
            id = genre._id;
            newName = 'updatedName';
        });

        it('should return 401 if client is not logged in', async () => {
            token = '';

            const res = await exec();

            expect(res.status).toBe(401);
        });
```

```
 ● /api/genres › PUT /:id › should return 401 if client is not logged in

    expect(received).toBe(expected) // Object.is equality

    Expected: 401
    Received: 200

      142 |             const res = await exec();
      143 |
    > 144 |             expect(res.status).toBe(401);
          |                                ^
      145 |         });
      146 |
      147 |         it('should return 400 if genre is less than 5 characters', async () => {

      at Object.toBe (tests/integration/genres.test.js:144:32)
```

Comment: you should also post the code that has the endpoint implementation to help understand what happens on that side

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Does the server perhaps respond with an HTML logon page in that case? That would have 200 OK.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to show us your route folder containing the endpoint for checking if a user is logged in, and also try to check if your auth middleware function is required on your endpoint.